# What sets the cap on the RAM a processor can access?

Tags: memory, processor

As per [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4RcMLFIr5o&list=PL0E131A78ABFBFDD0&index=2) lecture from a professor at IIT, an 8 bit 8085 processor would have 8 bit registers which can be paired to access 16 bit address. He enforces the fact that it can access 16 bit address by telling us that the program counter and stack pointer registers are 16 bit. He also goes on to tell us later, that the data bus is 8 bit but the address bus is 16 bit.

As a consequence wouldn't it mean that a 32 bit processor would be able to access a 64 bit address? But I know the max a 32 bit processor can address is about 4GB. What is it that sets this limit?

**Update:** Like some of you have pointed out, with PAE this address can be extended, but without PAE what is it that sets this limit? In other words why is there a 4GB cap on a 32 bit pentium processor without PAE?

Comment: @paulsm4 10b is only 1KB, IIRC 8085 was indeed using 16b addresses which is 64КB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A 8085 has 8 bit registers and 16 bits address space, but this doesn't mean 64 bit computer need to be able to access 128 bits. Each architecture is a different architecture.

The answer is that the only way to know the address space of the machine is for the manufacturer to tell you. Each address space is chosen for its own reasons. The 8086 had 16 bit registers and a 20 bit address space. ARM2 had 32 bit registers and 26 bit address space. The 80286 had 16 bit registers and 24 bit address space. amd64 has 64 bit registers and there are 40 bit and 48 bit physical address space implementations. Addresses may also be sent in multiple clock cycles to the memory controler. Bank switching could be used to allow arbitrary sized address spaces.

What's the address space of a Pentium processor ?

> Each byte is assigned a unique address, called a physical address, which ranges from zero to a maximum of 2^32–1 (4 gigabytes) -- Pentium Processor Family Developer's Manual, Volume 3: Architecture and Programming Manual

http://www.intel.com/design/pentium/MANUALS/24143004.pdf

What's the address space of a modern Intel 64 processor ?

> Intel 64 architecture increases the linear address space for software to 64 bits and supports physical address space up to 40 bits. -- Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual, Volume 1: Basic Architecture

http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf

What's the address space of a modern Intel processor when in 32 bit mode ?

> Address space — Any task or program running on an IA-32 processor can address a linear address space of up to 4 GBytes (2^32 bytes) and a physical address space of up to 64 GBytes (2^36 bytes) -- Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual, Volume 1: Basic Architecture

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

There are several limits:

1. The size of the address registers and address computation logic.
2. The number of physical address lines coming out of the processor.

With [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension), a 32-bit processor's address path is larger than 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct that a 32-bit processor could address only 4GB of ram, for example with [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) could adress up to 36-bit address space.

Basically the general rule is the same, it depens mostly on system board logic and CPU support of maximum address size (address register size).